# set var in Csh script

Tags: shell, sh, csh

I'm creating a script like this

```
#!/bin/csh

set h=1;

while [h=1] do  echo "hi"; h=2; done;
```

but when I execute it a get this:

```
===> message after : csh test.sh     [h=1]: No match.
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
set h = 1

while ( $h == 1 )
  echo "hi"
  set h = 2
end
```

You seem to be trying to mix Bourne shell syntax into your C shell script.

Csh is generally a lousy language for scripting, try to avoid it if at all possible

http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/shell/csh-whynot/

UPDATE:

The csh equivalent to `read h` is:

```
set h = $<
```

Comment: #!/bin/csh

set h = 1;

while ( $h == 1 )

echo "hi"

read h;
echo "write value deferent then 1"
read h
end

Comment: Don't try to put code in comments, all the formatting is lost. Edit your question. But the answer is that there's no `read` command in csh, that's Bourne shell as well. Please RTFM.

Comment: OK Thank you again , But there is allwayse an other probleme : look to all my script

Comment: The syntax to redirect stdout and stderr is `>&filename`, not `&>filename`. Why are you trying to write a script in csh if you have no idea what the syntax is? Please RTFM!!!!!!!

Comment: If I answered the original question, please accept my answer. If you have new problems, start a new question, don't put them in comments.

Comment: ok i will open new tab Question ? All your answers work correctly

Comment: `$?` is Bourne shell, the csh equivalent is `$status`. It seems like you know Bourne shell, why are you trying to write csh scripts like that? Do you understand that these are __very__ different?

Comment: yes i know but ;-) so sorry for this Q? , i need to convert my code to Csh fastly as possible but aftre i will read all the defferents betwin them i meen sh and csh . thank you a gain , i have creat a new tab Q : here pls take tour :